# How do you concatenate tensorflow tensors along axis 0 while preserving the shape of the other n>0 dimensions

Tags: python, list, tensorflow, reshape, tensor

My goal is to take a list of tensors of `shape(1, 2, ...n)` and concatenate them into a tensor of `shape(len(list), 1, 2, ..., n)`.

`tf.concat(list, -1)` does not work. It returns `shape(1, 2, ..., n-1*n)`, which is understandable.

`tf.concat(list, 0)` does not work. It return `shape(1*2, ..., n)` which I do not want. I tried to take this intermediate and use `features = tf.reshape(f, [len(list)])`, but I get one of two exceptions.

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: OpKernel 'ConcatV2' has constraint on attr 'T' not in NodeDef '[N=0, Tidx=DT_INT32]', KernelDef: 'op: "ConcatV2" device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list { type: DT_QINT32 } } } host_memory_arg: "axis"' [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat`

or something like this

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 120 values, but the requested shape has 2 [Op:Reshape]`

I have tried using `features = tf.reshape(f, [len(list), -1])` and get `shape(len(list), 1, 2, n-1*n)` which is also wrong, but understandable.

Only other thing I can think of is copying the shape like this, `tf.shape([len(list), list[0].shape])`, but that leads to error

`ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with mixed types to Tensor.`

I now tried

```
        f = tf.concat(list, 0)
        f = tf.expand_dims(f, 0)
        features = tf.reshape(f, [len(list)])
```

and still get an error

Is there some way to do this without making a hacky loop to go through the n dimensions of the shape?

Comment: Your question looks messy, please improve it.

Comment: Suggestions on ways to improve?

Comment: code block to separate code and text

Comment: @BrainFlooder you can propose an edit to gain reputation until you have 2000 or so; three back-tics ` can be used to create a code block

Comment: @ti7 I know but I can't even know which is the code and which isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Seems hacky, but this works

```
        if time_features is not None:
            s = [len(time_features)]
            for i in time_features[0].shape[:]:
                s.append(i)
            f = tf.concat(time_features, 0)
            features = tf.reshape(f, s)
```